# Undefined behaviour of const

Tags: c++, c

I never thought I will be going to ask this question but I have no idea why this happens.

```
const int a = 3; 
int *ptr;
ptr = (int*)( &a );
printf( "A=%d\n", &a );
*ptr = 5; 
printf( "A=%d\n", ptr );
printf( "A=%d\n", a );
printf( "A=%d\n", *ptr );
```

**Output**

```
A=6945404
A=6945404
A=3
A=5
```

How can this happen? How can one memory location hold two different values? I searched around and all I find is **undefined behavior is undefined**. Well that does not make any sense. There must be an explanation.

**Edit**

I get it, `Marks` answer makes alot of sense but still I wonder that const was added into the language so that user does not change the value unintentionally. I get that old compilers allows you to do that but I tried this on VS 2012 and I got the same behavior. Then again as `haccks` said, one memory location can't hold two values it looks like it does, then where is the second value stored?

Comment: Sorry my bad, see the edit

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen. The code might work exactly as expected, it might crash or it might steal your girlfriend.

Comment: Do you have any optimisation level configured in your compiler?

Comment: Yes, I do, I get what is happening but const was brought into the language just so users dont change the value unintentionally this why I got disturbed that why is it allowing me

Comment: You are casting a `const`-pointer to an unqualified one. All bets are off. As simple as that. Don't throw a kitchen knife if you don't know what you are targeting.

Comment: @Hamza The language does not allow you to write a `const` value without a diagnostic until code overrode that via `ptr = (int*)( &a );`

Comment: "How can one memory location hold two different values?" -- Why would you assume that a const has a memory location? "Well that does not make any sense." -- of course it does; a compiler is free to do ANYTHING when the behavior is undefined.

Comment: "why is it allowing me" -- because you TOLD it to with that cast.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The optimizer can determine that `a` is a constant value, and replace any reference to it with the literal `3`. That explains what you see, although there's no guarantee that's what's actually happening. You'd need to study the generated assembly output for that.

Comment: again my question is How can one memory location hold two different values. What exactly is in the stack? What if I create it dynamically and don't delete it? What will be left there? 3 or 5?

Comment: The optimizer replaces a with 3. It does not replace *ptr with 3 (though technically it's allowed to). Note that the statement *ptr = 5 may core dump on some OSes and compilers.

Comment: Hamza, You missed Mark's point. When you wrote `const int a=3;` you gave the compiler the option of interpreting every subsequence reference in the code to `a` as meaning 3 rather than the variable `a`.

Comment: @Hamza I was a bit unspecific. I meant to say that the call to `printf("%d",a)` was the one where a literal value was substituted. All the other statements use the one and only memory location. At least that's what I guess is happening without seeing the assembly output, as I said.

Comment: Yes I am using VS 2012 so I believe it should give me an error where I am changing constant value

Comment: @MarkRansom I like you answer, it makes sense but Compiler should give me an error I agree that behavior is undefined but const was brought into the language just so users dont change the value unintentionally.

Comment: @Hamza the compiler doesn't give you an error because you've intentionally lied to it. You cast away the `const` attribute when you created the pointer, so it has to assume you knew what you were doing and it wasn't really `const` to begin with. There are times I've had to do this when calling a function that didn't take a `const` pointer even though I knew it wasn't going to change the value. I had to hold my nose when I did it though.

Comment: Well I get all this. Its just that const is there so that compiler should not let me lie. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/357syhfh.aspx

Anyways can you tell me one more thing, as compiler says that both are on same memory location while they cannot so where is the second value stored?

Comment: @Hamza the second value is stored in the code itself. It's probably being loaded directly into a register, or pushed onto the stack just before the function call.

Comment: Thanks man, although i am still not 100% cleared but still you have cleared quiet alot :)

Comment: @Hamza in C++ preventing yourself from shooting yourself in the foot when you unsafely and deliberately override the type system is not considered the compiler's problem.  Such checks could be expensive, be it extra runtime checks or blocked optimizations (like the `a` `3` substitution).  The type system is there to help you, but it does not force you to play nice.

Comment: A variable declared as 'const' is permitted to be be stored in read-only memory, which will result in a segmentation violation when you attempt to modify it, but the language standard does not require it, and some operating systems do not have the concept of read-only memory.

Comment: @user3303729, yes it's permitted. But the question wasn't about possible outcomes, it was about the outcome in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

Modifying a const variable through a non-const pointer results in undefined behavior. Most ikely the optimizer is substituting the original value in this line:

```
printf( "A=%d\n", a );
```

**Look at the disassembly to verify this.**

The C Standard, subclause 6.7.3, paragraph 6 [ISO/IEC 9899:2011], states:
If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In fact your program invokes undefined behavior because of two reasons:
1.You are printing an address with wrong specifier `%d`. Correct specifier for that is `%p`.
2.You are modifying a variable with `const` specifier.

If the behavior is undefined then anything could happen. You may get either expected or unexpected result.
Standard says about it;

#### 3.4.3 undefined behavior

> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
> for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

Comment: even if I use `%p` it does not really matter, it has same address. Again How can one memory location hold two different values.

Comment: It can't. Since behavior is undefined, it seems that it is actually holding two values.

Comment: I thought everything is binary, whether it holds or not. Well it can't so where is the second value stored.. Food for thought

Comment: I am not sure where that value get stored.

Comment: If I become a compiler then it could be :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type of ptr is "pointer to int" not "pointer to const int".
You are then casting the address of 'a' (a const int) to be of type "pointer to int" and storing that address in ptr. The effect of this is that you are casting away the const-ness of a const variable.

This results in undefined behavior so your results may vary from compiler to compiler.

It is possible for the compiler to store 'a' in program ROM since it knows 'a' is a const value that can never be changed. When you lie to the compiler and cast away the const-ness of 'a' so that you can modify it through ptr, it may be invalid for ptr to actually modify the value of 'a' since that data may be stored in program ROM. Instead of giving you a crash, this compiler this time decided to point ptr to a different location with a different value this time. But anything could have happened since this behavior is undefined.

Comment: Brother, I always believed the same, I am using VS 2012 so thats why I got confused, it should give me an error where I am changing constant value

Comment: Whether it gives you an error or not is up to the compiler vendor since this situation is undefined by the standard. They can do anything in this situation and still be standard compliant.

Comment: The compiler would have a hard time figuring out that it should give an error because neither operation is illegal. You're allowed to cast away constness (in this case to a non-const pointer) and you're allowed to modify a value through the resulting non-const pointer.